# Can someone recommend a Javascript-based Image Editing software with selection tools?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, image-editor

I am looking for an Javascript-based image editing tool that has a selection feature.   I would like to select a region and manipulate only that region by adjusting certain attributes.

I am also open to implementing my own, and welcome javascript-based libraries for low level image operations.